# Guide for Session sharing between 2 WAR files in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

2 separate MAVEN projects have generated 2 WAR files after their respective builds. Then the WAR files are deployed in the Tomcat 8.5.5 servers. 2 WAR files have 2 different sessions and are unable to communicate between each other. I want a session share where both WAR files can communicate between each other.

Tried with Redis.
Adding the following in context.xml of Tomcat - 

And downloading JAR file of Redis. But unable to achieve it.

Comment: <Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager"
          configPath="${catalina.base}/redisson.conf" readMode="MEMORY" updateMode="DEFAULT"/> added in context.xml

Comment: The technology used for one WAR is struts-2 and another one is spring.